# Deduplicated tables SQL query to obtain the unique value

Tags: sql

I use SQL to query my database like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, 
                B,
                SUM(C) AS C
FROM TABLE
WHERE A = 2 AND DATE  >= 'xxxxx' AND DATE <= 'xxxxx'
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

I obtain this result :

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 32 |
| 2 | 1 | 32 |
| 2 | 2 | 32 |
| 2 | 3 | 32 |

How can i modify my query to obtain the unique row for the value 2 of column A ? Because i've some redundance in this table and i want the information agregated at the column A level and so i would like the result with only column A and C :

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 32 |

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ``select distinct A, C from (SELECT A,B,SUM(C) AS C FROM TABLE WHERE A = 2 AND DATE  >= 'xxxxx' AND DATE <= 'xxxxx' GROUP BY 1,2);``?

Comment: i found the answer like this : `                                                                    
    SELECT DISTINCT A, 
                SUM(C) AS C
FROM TABLE
WHERE A = 2 AND DATE  >= 'xxxxx' AND DATE <= 'xxxxx'
GROUP BY 1, B;                                                                                                            
` your answer works too thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by [@David Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11582270/david-lukas)

```
select distinct 
    A, 
    C 
from (
    SELECT 
        A,
        SUM(C) AS C
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE A = 2 
    AND DATE  BETWEEN 'xxxxx' AND <= 'xxxxx' 
    GROUP BY 1,2);
```